# VS Code create logic app error: Unable to write to Workspace Settings because azureFunctions.suppressProject is not a registered configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-logic-apps

If you are trying to create a logic app using Visual Studio Code and get the error:

> Unable to write to Workspace Settings because
> azureFunctions.suppressProject is not a registered configuration

Answer (score 0):

- Make certain you have started the Azure Storage emulator
- You have the Azure Functions extension installed in Visual Studio Code

See this link on gitub for more info: https://github.com/Azure/logicapps/issues/368